# /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:307: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator

Tags: c++, linux

I have some code, when I compile it, I got the following errors, and I don't know how to solve it. I have tried to add `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, `-lboost_system` and `-lboost_filesystem`, but I still got the same errors. I don't know how to fix this problem now, if anybody could help?

```
Agent.o: In function `boost::filesystem::path::append(char const*, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t> const&)':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:307: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(char const*)'
Agent.o: In function `boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:289: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
Agent.o: In function `boost::filesystem::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:399: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
Agent.o: In function `boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::path_traits::is_pathable<boost::decay<char [256]>::type>, boost::filesystem::path&>::type boost::filesystem::path::operator/=<char [256]>(char const (&) [256])':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:302: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [player] Error 1
```

The related code are as following

```
bool Agent::openTupleLog()
{
 std::string dir="~/Experiments/Nov/";
 // create the log directory & file path string


try
{
    boost::filesystem::path kaway_log( dir
#if defined(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION) && BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION == 2
#  ifndef BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
                                       , &boost::filesystem::native
#  endif
#endif
                                       );
    if ( ! boost::filesystem::exists( kaway_log )
         && ! boost::filesystem::create_directories( kaway_log ) )
    {
        std::cerr << __FILE__ << ": " << __LINE__
                  << ": can't create log directory '"
                  << kaway_log.BOOST_FS_DIRECTORY_STRING() << "'" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    kaway_log /= tuplesFilename;


   M_kaway_log_name = kaway_log.BOOST_FS_FILE_STRING();
}
catch ( std::exception & e )
{
    std::cerr << __FILE__ << ": " << __LINE__
              << " Exception caught! " << e.what()
              << "\nCould not create log directory '"
              << dir
              << "'" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

// open the output file stream
M_kaway_log.open( M_kaway_log_name.c_str() );

if ( ! M_kaway_log.is_open() )
{
    std::cerr << __FILE__ << ": " << __LINE__
              << ": can't open log_file " << M_kaway_log_name
              << std::endl;
    return false;
}

return true;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

I asked a friend, he told me to add `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system` at the end of the command, then it works. He said:

> The order of putting those flags are dependent, and thus I have to move the .a to very end. Then it ask for boost_system and thus I appended -lboost_system for its pleasure.

And note that it's `libboost_filesystem.a`, not `libboost_filesystem.so`

Comment: I have the same issue - at the end of which command?

Comment: ah, add it to `LD_FLAGS` it seems - I only needed `-lboost_filesystem` btw, hardcoding the path doesn't seem a good idea either